# Deactivate change request

Tags: abap

Our system landscape consists of four main environments:

1. Development
2. Quality Assurance
3. Integration
4. Production

Transportation routine between [1] and [3] is being done by releasing original Change Request from [1], assuring its content quality in [2] and finally transporting it from [2] to [3].

Transportation to [4] is being done mainly the same way.

However, commonly in big and long developments, multiple `CR`s which reached [3] are included in a new `CR` in [1]. Then released to [2], Then transported to [3], then to [4].
That way, there are some `CR` left behind in [3] which need to be abandoned. There is a risk (bad experience) that one day any of them would be transported to [4] and overwrite a more-recent version. Therefore, we want to block the ability of transporting them, without deleting them (for documentation purposes).

Comment: You can use "Transport of copies" to control this. I don't know enough to explain, but I'm a developer and see some companies using this to control the transportation to Production.

Comment: `Transport Of Copies` is like a regular `CR` in this context. It could left behind in integration, and be mistakenly transported to production

Comment: I think there is a parameter in production that prevents transport of "Transport of Copies". But I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Why don't you set [QA approval system](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/12/02/stms-qa-approval-configuration/)? You can set up up to three levels of approvers without whose permission it will be impossible to import requests. Details [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/de/2ea1397b0e1224e10000000a11402f/content.htm?no_cache=true).

**Option 2**

Another option is to set all these TRs as [local](https://help.sap.com/viewer/ff5932cd6c5510148c849afae8be934a/7.02.18/en-US/2e6d66797d9011d396b60000e82de14a.html) and assign authorizations of changing TR type only to selected people, thus requests cannot be transported accidentally.

**Option 3**

The most troubleproof and consistent way of doing this is to use ChARM for transporting and restrict to create/move requests locally. Here is [SAP Note](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2203520) how to set up it.

Comment: Option 1. is already set. However, sometimes there are human mistakes with giving approvals (Been there...).
Option 2. Sounds interesting, how to change an already released CR in integration environment?
Option 3. ChaRM has been abandoned by our organization years ago.

Comment: As per my knowledge, it is impossible to change request to local to already released requests, only to modifiable ones.

Comment: As an option, you can also [close import queue](https://help.sap.com/viewer/CTS75/44b4a3917acc11d1899e0000e829fbbd.html) after all necessary request were imported.